# Show Hide Style JavaScript TAB MENU

Tags: javascript

```
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
  }
```

Code need like upside but for buttons.i want when visitor click to a button hide all others and show just clicked one's div

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.visibility= 'visible';
} else {
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.visibility= 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: its still for dropdown i need for buttons can use elementid or get method

Comment: I dont understand your question. you can also talk in french or german if it is easier for you

Comment: i have <button onclick="" id="1">Menu 1</button><button onclick="" id="2">Menu 2</button> i want when i click menu 1 show a div named menu1_content and hide menu2_content if i click menu2 hide menu1 contect show menu1_content

Comment: you must write a function for that

Comment: i cant because i dont know javascript